# Transaction never confirmed over 2 days

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I did a transaction from my bitcoin core wallet.  The transaction 6263452f635713e60f83d45fe41b1c9ba3b5f5e3af664778bf18a05b15cfde06 has not confirmed, and it is now over 48 hours since I made the transaction.   Although blockchain.info will show the transaction (as unconfirmed) if I enter the transaction ID directly, it no longer shows it on the "unconfirmed transactions" page, https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions.

What should I do now?  I am a complete newbie - this is my first transaction, and this has been very frustrating.

Thanks.

Comment: bitcoin infrastracture is under attack for the last few days, maybe because of that

Answer (score -1):

Your transaction should be confirming shrtly(within 1 day)You did not send the appropriate miner fee which is why the transaction is slower to confirm. Do not worry tho it will confirm at some point tody:)

Comment: Thank you; I hope you're right.  What is the "appropriate" miner fee?  Inside bitcoin core, I set it at "normal"; is that a misleading setting?

Comment: If it hasn't confirmed within the last two days, what reason is there to think it will confirm today?

Comment: @NickODell If the tx is valid, its expected confirmation time is 10 minutes, regardless of how long it has been unconfirmed already. Given, network congestion make this issue more complex, but essentially it's the same kind of statistics as block mining times: the average time to mine a block is 10 minutes. However, even if no block has been found for over 3 hours already, at that point the expected time to find the next block is *still* 10 minutes.

Comment: @RocketNuts ...unless there's some problem that will prevent the transaction from getting into a block forever.

Comment: @NickODell I'd say "some problem that will prevent the transaction from getting into a block forever" and the tx being valid are mutually exclusive? Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't think of a scenario where a tx is technically valid (and thus is getting relayed normally, i.e. not directly rejected by normal nodes) yet unable to ever be included in a block?